# CustomStringLengthValidator Required - (patterns & practices – Enterprise Library)

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am using Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Validation Application Block.

I want override the `StringLengthValidator` which will have only one minor change.

The current `StringLengthValidator` is fine but the problem is this validator is doing two jobs., `NotNull` check and String length check. If the string is `null` then the validator is firing message even if I ignore the lower bound checking.

What I want is if I provide a `null` value the validator should not fire when I ignore the lowerbound checking, only it should consider upperBound.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Or Composite Validator that comes with Enterprise Library. You can have Not Null Validator and String Length Validator to perform your validation.

Here's a quick sample:

[ConfigurationElementType(typeof(CustomValidatorData))]
    public sealed class CustomValidatorClass : Validator
    {

```
    public CustomValidatorClass(string template, string tag)
        : base(template, tag)
    {

    }

    protected override string DefaultMessageTemplate
    {
        get { return "blah blah"; }
    }

    public override void DoValidate(object objectToValidate, object currentTarget, string key, ValidationResults validationResults)
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

In the configuration file:

```
<validation>
    <type name="ConsoleApplication1.PropertyClass" assemblyName="ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <ruleset name="Validation Ruleset">
            <properties>
                <property name="MyProperty">
                    <validator type="ConsoleApplication1.MyClass, ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
                        messageTemplate="Blah blah" name="MyClass" />
                </property>
            </properties>
        </ruleset>
    </type>
</validation>
```

You can use the generic class for any specific type you want to validate or any of the classes that already extend Validator class in Enterprise Library API.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.  But every time I have to use two validators. I am looking for a permanent solution like creating a CustomStringLengthValidator and I like to learn more on making custom validators.

Comment: You can create your own validator for this purpose by extending ValueValidator class.

Comment: well...but in the above example how do I pass the MaxLength which is required to validate against the length of string.

Comment: You need to work your way through it. I am not going to write code for you. At least not for free. :)

Comment: @SukeshChand, take a look at [Hands-On Labs for Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6932).  There are exercises for creating custom validators.